# Handling overflow in SMT-LIB/Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I'm trying to model the following expression using SMT `a + b - c - d`, all constants `a,b,c,d` are bitvecs of the same size, constraint with the following assert `a + b >= c + d`. I want to model it in such a way that overflows/underflows don't happen.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
(declare-const a (_ BitVec 4))
(declare-const b (_ BitVec 4))
(declare-const c (_ BitVec 4))
(declare-const d (_ BitVec 4))

(assert (bvuge (bvadd a b) (bvadd c d)))

; this is an inaccurate, only checks the last operation for underflow
; (a+b-c-d) >= d
; (assert (bvuge (bvsub (bvsub (bvadd a b) c) d) d))
;
; this should model that either both sides overflow, neither,
; or only the expression to the left of the inequality
; (
;     (a + b <= a and c + d <= c and a + b >= c + d) or
;     (a + b >= a and c + d <= c) or
;     (a + b >= a and c + d >= c and a + b >= c + d)
; )
;(assert (or
;        (and (bvule (bvadd a b) a)
;             (bvule (bvadd c d) c)
;             (bvuge (bvadd a b) (bvadd c d)))
;        (and (bvuge (bvadd a b) a)
;             (bvule (bvadd c d) c))
;        (and (bvuge (bvadd a b) a)
;             (bvuge (bvadd c d) c)
;             (bvuge (bvadd a b) (bvadd c d)))))

(assert (bvuge (bvsub (bvsub (bvadd a b) c) d) #x0))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

But I'm not sure if the constraint are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

A better strategy is to "extend" to larger bit-vectors and check that the result fits in the bit-vector size you want. Note that proper underflow/overflow checking for bit-vectors can be surprisingly tricky, especially in the presence of multiplication.

Luckily, there's an excellent paper that describes how to do this properly: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/z3prefix.pdf

(There are a few minor issues with the paper: a few typos here and there, and the signed-multiplication overflow/underflow formula is outdated. But it's an excellent resource to start with!)

Furthermore, Z3 also provides out-of-the-box checker predicates for multiplication under/over-flows.

Once you review the paper, feel free to ask further questions regarding its contents if you still have issues!